# Invalid characters before my XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, rexml

When I look in an XML file, it looks fine, and starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16le" standalone="yes"?>`

But when I read it in Ruby and print it to stout, there are two ?s in front of that: `??<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16le" standalone="yes"?>`

Where do these come from, and how do I remove them? Parsing it like this with REXML fails immediately. Removing the first to characters and then parsing it, gives me this error:

`REXML::ParseException: #<REXML::ParseException: malformed XML: missing tag start
Line: 
Position: 
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16le" s>`

What is the right way to handle this?

**Edit:** Below is my code. The `ftp.get` downloads the xml from an ftp server. (I wonder if that might be relevant.)

```
xml = ftp.get
puts xml
until xml[0,1] == "<"  # to remove the 2 invalid characters
  puts xml[0,2]
  xml.slice! 0
end
puts xml
document = REXML::Document.new(xml)
```

The last puts prints the correct xml. But because of the two invalid characters, I've got the feeling something else went wrong. It shouldn't be necessary to remove anything. I'm at a loss what the problem might be, though.

**Edit 2:** I'm using Net::FTP to download the XML, but with this new method that lets me read the contents into a string instead of a file:

```
class Net::FTP

  def gettextcontent(remotefile, &block) # :yield: line
    f = StringIO.new()
    begin
      retrlines("RETR " + remotefile) do |line|
        f.puts(line)
        yield(line) if block
      end
    ensure
      f.close
      return f
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit 3:** It seems to be caused by StringIO (in Ruby 1.8.7) not supporting unicode. I'm not sure if there's a workaround for that.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the real problem here is that encoding support in Ruby 1.8.7 is lacking. StringIO is particular seems to make a mess of it. REXML also has trouble handling unicode in Ruby 1.8.7.

The most attractive solution would be of course to upgrade to 1.9.3, but that's not practical for this project right now.

So what I ended up doing is, avoid StringIO and simply download to a file on disk, and then instead of processing the XML with REXML, use nokogiri instead.

Together, that solves all my problems.

Answer (score 5):

Those 2 characters are most likely a [unicode bom](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html): bytes that tell whoever is reading the file what the byte order is.

As long as you know what the encoding of the file is, it should be safe to strip them - they aren't actual content

Comment: Thanks!That certainly clears that up. Although since it specifies utf-16le, that BOM shouldn't be necessary, should it? But more importantly, it doesn't explain why REXML::Document.new fails.

Comment: @mcv Probably because it doesn't expect the BOM... Strip it off and try again?

Comment: @Romain I stripped off the BOM. Check the my code: until xml[0,1] == "<"  # to remove the 2 invalid characters
  puts xml[0,2]
  xml.slice! 0
end

Comment: it's probably assuming utf-8 or something like that. Is the bom that you are stripping consistent with the encoding and with the encoding in the processing directive

Comment: @FrederickCheung I have absolutely no idea. How can I check?

Comment: I'd inspect the bytes by hand (e.g. hex dump)

Comment: If I read the file I ftp'd by hand, it works. So the problem is either the Ruby based ftp or the way I'm putting that directly into a string.

Comment: Are you transferring the file in binary mode?

Comment: Text mode. But when I do it manually, my mac's ftp says it only suports stream mode, whatever that is.

Comment: Getting it as binary doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I think the problem is that StringIO doesn't support unicode. The fact that I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 is probably relevant.

Comment: @mcv Using 1.8.x is relevant. Use 1.9.x or process the file through IConv, maybe?

Comment: I'll just save it to disk for now and then read it in again. Not as pretty as I'd like, but it'll do. Perhaps later I can upgrade to 1.9.3.